# スライドに張り付けたmp3をPowerPoint 2016のVBAを使って自動再生モードにしたい

Tags: vba, powerpoint

VBAでスライドに貼り付けたmp3を、自動再生モードにしたいのですが、PowerPOint2016では意図した通り処理されずに困っています。

下記コードは、PowerPoint2013では、期待どおり動き、mp3は自動再生になります。
しかし、PowerPoint2016に対して、下記コードを実行すると「自動」再生ではなく「一連のクリック」というメニューitemが選択されてしまいます。

2016になってから、[なし]、[自動再生]に加えて、「一連のクリック」というメニューアイテムが増えてしまった事に依るものと思われます。解決策をご教授ください。

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim OLEobj As Shapes
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

    Set OLEobj = ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Shapes
    
    For j = 1 To OLEobj.Count
        If OLEobj(j).Type = MsoShapeType.msoMedia Then
            If OLEobj(j).MediaType = ppMediaTypeSound Then
                With OLEobj(j).AnimationSettings.PlaySettings
                    .PlayOnEntry = True
                    '.ActionVerb = "Edit"
                End With
            End If
        End If
    
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: 同じテーマの複数の質問で情報が出てこないようですが、こちら [Microsoft 365 および Office Microsoftコミュニティ](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum) の方で聞いてみてはどうでしょう？ こんなやり取りもあるようですし。[PowerPoint アニメーションウインドウ＞再生オーディオ＞タイミング＞繰り返し…の繰り返しループが作動しなくなった](https://answers.microsoft.com/ja-jp/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint/ac5a5ddd-8e87-40c9-b860-943acb9991f6)

Comment: @kunif ご教授いただきありがとうございます。ぜひ試したいと存じます。